# Different space above and below mathtools \intertext

Tags: mathtools, vertical-spacing

Is there a command like `\intertext` or `\shortintertext` that has different vertical space above and below the "intertext"? It would be nice in situations such as a few of those in the example below.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    a^2 + b^2 &= c^2 \\
    \shortintertext{and also} % shortintertext works fine
    a^2 + b^2 &= c^2 \\
    \shortintertext{and also} % space above should be as shortintertext and space below should be as intertext
    \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \sum_{j = 1}^{N} \frac{\omega_{i} \omega_{j} Y_{i}}{Y} \!\left(2 \Phi\!\left[\frac{\ln Y_{i} - \ln Y_{j} + 0.5 \sigma_{i}^{2} + 0.5 \sigma_{j}^{2}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{i}^{2} + \sigma_{j}^{2}}}\right]\! - 1\right) &= 0.5 \\
    \intertext{and also} % intertext works fine
    \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \sum_{j = 1}^{N} \frac{\omega_{i} \omega_{j} Y_{i}}{Y} \!\left(2 \Phi\!\left[\frac{\ln Y_{i} - \ln Y_{j} + 0.5 \sigma_{i}^{2} + 0.5 \sigma_{j}^{2}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{i}^{2} + \sigma_{j}^{2}}}\right]\! - 1\right) &= 0.5 \\
    \shortintertext{and also} % space above should be as intertext and space below should be as shortintertext
    a^2 &= c^2 - b^2 \\
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of writing `\!\left`, `\!\left[`, and `\right]\!`, I suggest you load the `mleftright` package in the preamble and write `\mleft(`, `\mleft[`, and `\mright]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manually add height or depth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{mleftright} % https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mleftright
\mleftright

\newcommand{\addheight}[1]{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+#1}}
\newcommand{\adddepth}[1]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{0pt}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    a^2 + b^2 &= c^2 \\
    \shortintertext{and also} % shortintertext works fine
    a^2 + b^2 &= c^2 \\
    \shortintertext{and also\adddepth{1.5ex}} % space above should be as shortintertext and space below should be as intertext
    \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \sum_{j = 1}^{N} \frac{\omega_{i} \omega_{j} Y_{i}}{Y} \left(2 \Phi\left[\frac{\ln Y_{i} - \ln Y_{j} + 0.5 \sigma_{i}^{2} + 0.5 \sigma_{j}^{2}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{i}^{2} + \sigma_{j}^{2}}}\right] - 1\right) &= 0.5 \\
    \intertext{and also} % intertext works fine
    \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \sum_{j = 1}^{N} \frac{\omega_{i} \omega_{j} Y_{i}}{Y} \left(2 \Phi\left[\frac{\ln Y_{i} - \ln Y_{j} + 0.5 \sigma_{i}^{2} + 0.5 \sigma_{j}^{2}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{i}^{2} + \sigma_{j}^{2}}}\right] - 1\right) &= 0.5 \\
    \shortintertext{and also\addheight{1.5ex}} % space above should be as intertext and space below should be as shortintertext
    a^2 &= c^2 - b^2
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I incorporated Mico's suggestion about `mleftright`.

[image]

Comment: +1: I took the liberty to add a link to parenthesis package since it is less known (at least to me). Feel free to reverse the edit if you don't like it.